# Month-long bitcoin subscription on .onion sites: How are returning subscribers identified each day?

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing, darknet, bitcoin

If a month-long subscription is paid in Bitcoin to an .onion site using Tor browser, how does that site still recognize/identify the same anonymous user when the return in subsequent sessions, given that Tails OS wipes the computer clean of any previous encounter with that site, as well as erases its accounting of the bitcoin wallet used to pay the subscription?

(If in some cases) no username or password set-up seems to accompany these paid subscriptions, Isn't there a risk of the site not recognizing the returning subscriber and barring access the next day, because they scrubbed their system per session, and therefore forfeiting their subscription prematurely?

Answer (score 2):

If no login/password is implemented in any form, then it is 100% scam.

Comment: but in the case that a login and password *is* registered, accompanied by a (returned) confirming transaction on the blockchain, whose amount is a value equal to the PIN code they assigned the registrant, then the bitcoin subscription can be trusted? that is, the username and password chosen by the registrant is indefinitely put into a database for future log-ins from (by Tor's nature) anonymous locations?

Comment: Any transaction is based on trust. It is your choice. For me it looks very sketchy to asingn PIN from returned transaction. It is counterintuitive to send you money back instead of writing 10 lines code to generate PIN serverside.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it's satisfactory for you. Thanks

Comment: i have added a question about how they even automate bitcoin subscriptions https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/how-to-automate-bitcoin-wallet-to-send-return-payments-to-website-subscribers

Comment: Do you want to post an example url? Be mindful about it.

Comment: mindful? many .onion merchants do this

Comment: At this point I am at loss. My answer stands regardless. It's that simple. If no user authentication form besides cookies is present it is 100% scam. Period.

Comment: do you know how to automate bitcoin website subscriptions https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/how-to-automate-bitcoin-wallet-to-send-return-payments-to-website-subscribers

Comment: It's a strangely convoluted way to authorize users you proposed there. I see no reason why you can't do it easy way. Unless you have to do it this way for whatever mysterious reasons.

Comment: I'm not aware of an alternative set-up for selling subscriptions that doesn't require an intermediary like BTCPay Server, do you? One way or another, a payment code has to be assigned and entered into the registration form. sometimes it is done as a print-out on-screen rather than being hidden in a return payment actually

Comment: Payment code for bitcoin payment? Now I'm really confused. Are you asking now how to setup payments instead of your original question? Because it's apples and oranges.

Comment: payment for a subscription (which requires a way to link the user registration (which has to be stored for the duration of membership) with the payment) as opposed to payment for a good (which doesn't require user registration, only one-time storage of shipping address)

Comment: I'm sorry. Can't be of any help here.